# C++ "*" Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to make a vector class in c++. I have overloaded the * operator like this:

```
class vector2
{
public:
    vector2(float x, float y);

    static vector2 vector_zero;

    float x, y;
    float length() const;
    string to_string();

    vector2 operator+(vector2 other);
    vector2 operator*(float other);
};

vector2 vector2::operator*(float other)
{
    return vector2(x * other, y * other);
}
```

It works fine when I write "vector2(3,4) * 2" but I want it to work when I write "2 * vector(3,4)" too. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create another `operator*` (outside of the class) like this:

```
vector2 operator*(float other, vector2 v){
  return v*other;
}
```

Side note:

you forgot a lot of the `const` declarations, an I also recommend using reference (`&`) for classes. I would also make these functions `inline`, because they are so small:

```
class vector2
{
public:
...
  string to_string() const;
  inline vector2 operator+(const vector2 &other)const;
  inline vector2 operator*(float other)const;
};

inline vector2 operator*(float other, const vector2 &v){
  return v*other;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will consider your advices.